# I am not allowed to run a python executable on other pcs

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, pyinstaller

I was doing a game in tkinter, then I make it executable with `PyInstaller` and sent it to my friends so they can run it and tell me how it feels.
It seems that they could download the file, but can't open it because windows forbade them telling that it's not secure and not letting them choose to assume the risk or something.
They tried to run as administrator and still nothing changed.

What should I do or what I should add to my code so that windows can open it without problem and why windows opens other executable files without saying that(current error that my executable gets)?

Comment: You can't write code that does that. If you could do that, there would be a lot of malware on your computer. Tell them to temporarily turn off their anti-malware software, so they can use it. Also, how did you send them the executable? Gmail forbades you to send them!

Comment: yeah i know. u can do that in some ways. first u can change the exe file extension in something ( u can choose whatever u want), send it and then ask them to change it back to exe. or u can add it to your drive(onedrive, google, etc.) and send them the link

Comment: @TheMaker there is no other method that allows them to run it without disable the anti-malware software?

Comment: Hey, I was just wandering if you had run `--hidden-import tkinter` on the pyinstaller, sometimes it doesn't pickup the fact tkinter is imported and that can cause issues?

Comment: @will Yes, I know of no other method. It shouldn't take long, should it?

Comment: @TheMaker soory u lost me, what should not take long?

Comment: @will Disabling the antivirus shouldn't take long, right?

Comment: @TheMaker now it shouldn t but i hopped that u came up with something so they shouldn t belive that my code contain something harming

Comment: @wowcha i can give u the file compiled with that so u could try to run it and see

Comment: @will Sorry man, I don't really know how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: @wowcha You shouldn't share your email here, you will get a lot of spam email and people will hack you.

Answer (score 0):

compress it as a .zip file and then it will most probably work

or install NSIS and create a windows installer for it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what I had to done

When the dialog appeared u need to click more info and then it will display a `Run Anyway` button
[image]